# More Than One Report In A Crystal Reports Executable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Hopefully a simple question.

Is it possible to have more than one report inside of a Crystal Reports executable that is created when building a Crystal Reports Project when the reports aren't linked? Not so that they run concurrently, but so that the user does not need to have multiple executables.

If so, how? I'm fairly sure that if it is possible, I've just over looked something.

**EDIT** Reworded accordingly.

Comment: you may want to consider re-wording the question- be a little more specific on what you are doing and what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply right click the project in the solution explorer and click Add then New Item or Existing Item, and you can add as many reports as you like.

Comment: I know that, but what I'm asking is how do you allow the user to switch to a different report within the same executable?

Comment: i don't have my visual studio pc in front of me but from memory you just change the crystalviewer.reportsource then do the usual looping to connect to the correct data source, populate any parameters then crystalviewer.refresh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply create multiple ReportDocument instances.

You may also want to create a ThreadPool to manage these instances.  As I recall, I used this approach when I was building a high-volume, bursting service.

Comment: or recycle the same report document

Comment: Agreed, but the wording of his question suggested that he want to generate more than one report concurrently.

Comment: you could create a pool of report documents that get reused by a concurrency manager when they are no longer being used so that you get the best of reusing objects and threrad pooling but that may be slight overkill(!)